# Key management on repeating elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I need a component that, given some children, it will repeat this children over and over to fill the screen. Let's say it has a simple markdown like this:

```html
<FillScreen items={[
    { id: 'one', content: 'foo' },
    { id: 'two', content: 'bar' }
]} />
```

Internally, this component will get the screen size, and will eventually fill the screen with these items. The resulting DOM will look like this:

```html
<div class="fill-screen">
   <div>foo</div>
   <div>bar</div>
   <div>foo</div>
   <div>bar</div>
   <div>foo</div>
   <div>bar</div>
   <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when this element has calculated that it needs to render 7 elements, I can't directly use `items[i].id` as a key for each element because there will be repeated keys.

I'm not sure what's the best pattern for this problem, I've thought two possible solutions which I don't fully like:

**Solution A**

Append  a loop index on every key, so the array in render contains the following JSX:

```html
   <div key='one-0'>foo</div>
   <div key='two-0'>bar</div>
   <div key='one-1'>foo</div>
   <div key='two-1'>bar</div>
   <div key='one-2'>foo</div>
   <div key='two-2'>bar</div>
   <div key='one-3'>foo</div>
```

Edit - note that these elements are being generated into an array, that's why we need to specify a `key`

I see two issues with this approach:

- At this point I may just get rid of the original key and just use an index, something that's absolutely discouraged.
- My real-life component, the way you give items to this component is through children (I oversimplified in here to get the point across), so I would have to clone each element just to change the key.

**Solution B**

Use fragments to separate between loops

```html
   <Fragment key={0}>
     <div key='one'>foo</div>
     <div key='two'>bar</div>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment key={1}>
     <div key='one'>foo</div>
     <div key='two'>bar</div>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment key={2}>
     <div key='one'>foo</div>
     <div key='two'>bar</div>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment key={3}>
     <div key='one'>foo</div>
   </Fragment>
```

In here it feels more clean, but at the same time this is not the reason Fragments were added in the first place, so maybe it's misusing them?.

Is there a better solution to this problem? What's the community standard?

Comment: Personally, I'd go with Solution A. I use lodash [uniqueId](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqueId) to provide uniqueIds. I doubt `key` is something we as consumer should be worried about, AFAIK React internals uses that to mutate the DOM tree. 
This boils down to which solution can make the subsequent ( children component? ) loosely coupled. Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: Are the elements with the same id equal ? Then you only need to render one per id.

Comment: "At this point I may just get rid of the original key and just use an index, something that's absolutely discouraged."
This is only an issue if you had actual data in an array where the position of some data in the array might change. If you have a fixed order of `foo` and `bar` though, this would not be an issue and by far the most simple and elegant solution IMHO.

Comment: @user3637541 But in this case the data we're using comes from an array in the component's props, so you don't really know if that data will change or not (and in the real-world example it will, it's eventually connected to a database). In here I just presented a simplified version that could be written in storybook to make the question more specific

Comment: In that case you should use an ID that is unique to that blob of data that you want to stick the `key` onto. So a database-generated-ID would be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `Fragment` I assume that you are using version >16. In that case I think that there is another (perhaps better) way of solving this problem, which is returning an Array of Arrays. Something like this:

```
[
  [
    <div key='one'>foo</div>,
    <div key='two'>bar</div>,
  ],
  [
    <div key='one'>foo</div>,
    <div key='two'>bar</div>,
  ],
  [
    <div key='one'>foo</div>,
  ],
]
```

Actually this is "equivalent" to your "Solution B", but IMHO is less "hacky" because *I think* that `Fragment` is not meant to be used like that. Let me extend on that:

Before version 16 the render function couldn't return an Array of React Elements, which was something quite annoying. On version 16 that started being possible, however the elements of the Array must always have a `key` so that the React's reconciler works properly, meaning that returning  this from a render function is bad:

```
[
  <span>foo</span>,
  <span>bar</span>,
]
```

and this is correct:

```
[
  <span key="firstSpan">foo</span>,
  <span key="secondSpan">bar</span>,
]
```

But doing that is a bit weird and annoying. That's why `Fragment` was invented, so that we can just return this:

```
<Fragment>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</Fragment>
```

So, the big advantage of `Fragment` is that we don't have to assign `keys` to their children elements. That's why I find it a bit hacky to see a `Fragment` with "keyed" children.

Also, I wanted to say that I don't think that there is anything wrong with your "Option A". However, I think that in most cases the solution that I'm proposing will be a lot easier to implement.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize I didn't need fragments at all. With solution B I was just creating a redundant element React doesn't really need. I actually like this solution better than A or B because it has the best of both worlds

Answer (score -1):

The right thing to use as key depends on what can change over the lifecycle of the parent component (`FillScreen`).

Using index as key is usually frowned upon because if `items` props changes during the lifecycle of `FillScreen`, then the same index can now point to another item but the component will not re-render because key remains the same.

In this case you can simply use a combination of `id` and `index` as the key but keep in mind that if the items get reshuffled in the array then the components for presenting every item will get remounted. The same is the case with the other approach using index keys on fragments (there is no particular advantage of using fragments here).

Similarly if you inject an item in between the array, then the components for presenting all subsequent items will get discarded and recreated.

If you do want to optimize for the above cases, you can construct the key by appending occurance index of that id.

```
<div class="fill-screen">
   <div key="one-0">foo</div>
   <div key="two-0">bar</div>
   <div key="one-1">foo</div>
   <div key="two-1">bar</div>
   <div key="one-2">foo</div>
   <div key="two-2">bar</div>
   <div key="one-3">foo</div>
</div>
```

React elements are fairly lightweight so cloning does not incur a significant cost overhead.

Comment: I understand this and I was aware of why it's better to use a combination of `id` and `index` than just `index`, but I was explaining just the things that to me made me feel those two solutions were not absolutely right. The question asks between these two solutions which one is better (which I get the point, solution A - I shouldn't worry about what I exposed) or if there's any other better alternative. Sorry I didn't make myself clear enough.

Comment: Yes. I am proposing that there is a better alternative: Append occurance index of id instead of loop index. And the reason why this is better is explained in the answer.